# An interval where the Polynomial is strictly positive

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I have tried this problem by comparison method and also tried to show that the polynomial is not crossing the x-axis in that interval but I failed. Moreover, the polynomial can be positive in other intervals too but how can I show for all x in the given interval.
Any help will be truly appreciated.

[image: The problem]

Answer (score 2):

$Q(x)/x^k=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}\dots +a_1x+1$

Now if $0<x<1$ then $x^m<x$, so  $a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}\dots +a_1x+1>-(|a_n|x+|a_{n-1}|x\dots +|a_1|x)+1$

$=1-x(|a_n|+|a_{n-1}|+\dots +|a_2|+|a_1|)$ for all $x\in (0,1)$

For $x\in (-1,0)$ use the fact that the value of the polynomial is greater than
$=1+x(|a_n|+|a_{n-1}|+\dots +|a_2|+|a_1|)$

Hence it's positive in the interval given in the question.

Comment: You need not care about that because you are asked to prove that the polynomial is positive for some values of $x$ which belongs to the interval $(0,1)$.

Comment: no it says |x|, so we also have an interval in the negative x axis.

Comment: For example, 0<|x|<1/2, here -1/3 also satisfies for x.

Comment: ok...use the same logic...what is the maximum negative it can attain?

Comment: its done, thanks a lot.